# Live change when browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have using this code for add div after 6 & 4 item in sequence according to screensize. It is working fine on load, but it does not work on browser resize.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize > 1024) {
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(6n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>');
    }
});

$(function () {
    $screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize < 1025) {
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(4n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></div>');
    }
})
})
```

---

**Updated:**

Thanks for all answer. but, it is not work perfectly according to want I. When, I have change more than 1 time screensize so, it is every time call(add more than 1 div).

**It would look like this:**

if, device width is more than 1024. So, Counter will calculate 6(add clearfix div after 6 item). & if device width is less than 1024 So. Counter will calculate 4(add clearfix div after 4 item).

**if device width is > 1024**

```
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
```

**if device width is < 1024**

```
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
```

I hope, you can clearly understand my question. Thanks.

Comment: use `window.resize` event and set as above. It is working first time bcase you have write on load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check when the user resize the browser use [$.resize](http://api.jquery.com/resize/), like this:

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $screensize = $(window).width();
    if ($screensize > 1024) {
        $(".clearfix.visible-lg-block").remove();
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(6n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>');
    } 
    if ($screensize < 1024) {
        $(".clearfix.visible-lg-block").remove();
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(4n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></div>');
    } 
});
```

NOTE: please conside if the `width == 1024` what will happen.

Comment: I have updated our question. I hope, you can clearly understand my question now. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I have create one issue. When first time load in `< 1024` and `> 1024`. so, it is not working. any solution? it is work on change device screensize. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, you need to put it on inside `document.ready` but outside this `$(window).resize`.. Actually I think you can use your code above as you stated it works fine on load..

Comment: Thanks, my and your both code are use. So it is working.

Comment: any possibility there both code to one code for short code.

Comment: You can put the code inside my resize function into another public function. Then you can call it inside `document.ready` and inside my `window.resize`.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `resize` event and use conditional statements inside the handler to manipulate your DOM:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(this).width() > 1024) {
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(6n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block"></div>');
    } else {
        $('#menu .nav > li.categories_hor > div > .column:nth-child(4n)').after('<div class="clearfix visible-lg-block visible-md-block"></div>');
    }
});
```

To trigger this manually onload, do:

```
$(function() { $(window).resize() }); // trigger resize onload
```

Note that you might want to change your DOM manip logic to toggle classes and visibility using CSS instead, as it is now you will be adding multiple elements on resize.

Comment: I have updated our question. I hope, you can clearly understand my question now. Thanks.